# How to use parallel page factory

Tags: java, selenium

I have tests that need to run in Parallel. For example, 
We have client A, B, C. All of these clients have the same exact tests being done to them, with all Elements of the web-page being the same. As of right now the method being used is

```
Client A <-----> Client A page factory
Client B <-----> Client B page factory
Client C <-----> Client C page factory
```

If we try to run more then 1 client per page factory at the same time, with Selenium we get null pointer exception because the driver becomes null. One solution we saw was using Page Object Map to handle Web-elements, and driver does not become null. However, that practice isn't allowed at my workplace.

So, question is, Is there a way to have one Page factory for multiple clients to run at the same time. Thanks

Comment: Could you post your code please? This makes it easier to help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, there really isn't code to show. More of a logic question here

Comment: @user9900402 - Without a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) its hard to say what could be wrong.

Comment: @user9900402 if u dont have code, it is strange u got a specific nullpointerexception?

Comment: Why would a "programming practice" not be allowed at a workplace?  That makes no sense.